# Visual Studio 9: Display Linker Search Paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linker

How do I convince the MSVC9 linker to show me which paths it is searching for include libraries (`lib`s) in?

I am trying to solve a problem where I am getting the following linker error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MyGizmo.lib'
```

Under **Linker** > **General**, I have *Additional Library Directories* set as:

```
..\..\..\x64\Release
```

Which is, I thought, where the lib file I'm looking for resides.

When I change this path to the fully-qualified directory where the lib file is, the linker passes and finds the lib file.  Therefore, I conclude that the way I have entered my relative path above is incorrect.  If the path is relative to where the source code lives, this relative path *should* be correct.

So how do I tell the MSVC9 linker to tell me what it thinks `..\..\..\x64\Release` resolves to?

Comment: Since you know exactly where your lib's reside, you might want to consider using fully qualified paths through macros instead (e.g. `$(SolutionDir)`). You can combine those with relative paths as well: `$(SolutionDir)..\..\..\x64\Release`. This way you don't have to rely on the current working directory.

Comment: can't vouch for 2008 but in both 2005 and 2010 the path is relative to the project directory (not the solution directory)

Comment: @IInspectable:  That was something I attempted, and it also didn't work.  That's what ultimately led me to scratch my head and post.

Comment: @John That's odd. At any rate, to answer your initial question, you should specify the [/VERBOSE:LIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx) linker option. This will print output from library search process (including full paths).

Comment: @IInspectable:  I did that, too, but it didn't display the *paths* -- it only displayed the libraries that it was considering.

Comment: @John I'm still puzzled why you cannot seem to get this to work using the build macros. Is this a project you have upgraded from an earlier version of Visual Studio? Also, when using the build macros from the configuration dialog, the expanded contents are displayed as well. Do those match the expected locations?

Comment: @IInspectable:  No, this is a brand-new project I just constructed from zero.  Yes, the expanded macros do match the expected locations.  It was all very odd to me as well.

Comment: @John This sounds like your project is a dependency of the library project. Have you properly set up the project dependencies? Related to dependencies, you might want to use `$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)` instead of `x64\Release`. (I hope you don't mind me nagging; this just happens to be an interesting effect.)

Comment: @IInspectable:  Once I figured out the correct relative pathname, I did change it to use `$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)` rather than `x64\Release`, and it works just fine now.  I think the core problem here was that I had a solution directory and then a project subdirectory below that, so I was missing one level of ` ..\` .  This project isn't dependant upon any other project.  I simply wanted VS to tell me what it thought `..\..\etc` meant, so that I could tweak the inderection.

Comment: /verbose passed to lib.exe or link.exe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out one way to do this after posting my question above.  I don't know if this is an advisable method, but it worked for me and I was able to solve the problem.

I created a custom pre-link step which simply issued a `cd` command with no arguments, to display the current working directory.

Under **Configuration Properties** > **Build Events** > **Pre-Link Event**, I set the *Command Line* property to:

```
cd
```

On building again, the output was:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyThingy, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Performing Pre-Link Event...
1>c:\build\VS2008\SuperWare\Some\Library\
1>Linking...
```

The library I'm looking for is located under:

```
c:\build\vs2008\SuperWare\Tools\Gizmo\x64\Release
```

From this I was able to deduce the relative path I need is:

```
..\..\Tools\Gizmo\x64\Release
```

I changed the *Additional Library Directories* property accordingly, and the build succeeded.